# Recognizing runes drawn by user

Tags: c#, unity, gestures

I want to implement a system where the player can draw runes on the screen with multiple gestures. Meaning its not just one motion it can be up to 3. So far I have implemented the [$P Recognizer](https://depts.washington.edu/aimgroup/proj/dollar/pdollar.html) . In the example it works great and is exactly what I want. But its made with .Net 4.0 and the dll does not work with unity. I eventually managed to get it working by compiling down to 3.5. The problem is that  the integration in unity does not work well at all. It recognizes the shape but when I draw wrong symbols it recognizes them as well. I'm completely lost as how to proceed fixing this. Here is my code that handles the integration.

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            clone = Instantiate(trailHolderPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            clone.transform.SetParent(transform);
            i++;
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {

            points.Add(new Point(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, i));

            Ray r = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            Vector3 pos = r.GetPoint(_distance);
            transform.position = pos;
        }
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {

            if(i>=3)
            {
                i = 0;
                Point[] _points = points.ToArray();
                Gesture candidate = new Gesture(_points);
                string gestureCLass = PointCloudRecognizer.Classify(candidate, trainingSet);
                spellname.text = gestureCLass;
            }
            clone.transform.parent = null;
            clone.GetComponent<TrailRenderer>().autodestruct = true;

          // GestureXML.GestureIO.WriteGesture(_points, "Triangle",Application.persistentDataPath+"test"+i.ToString()+".xml");
        }
```

Comment: $P Recognizer uses a nearest-neighbour-based algorithm. That means when you give it a symbol that's not in its recognized set, it will give you the nearest recognized symbol. If you want to reject incorrectly-drawn symbols, then you'll need to add classification data for these error cases, so that when the user draws one, the error data is the nearest neighbour, rather than one of the correct symbols.

Comment: @DMGregory oooohhhhhhhhhh. This makes so much sense. So have I made a bad decision going for $P ? Any suggestions on what else can I use ?

Comment: You may be able to make $P do what you want by providing it more training data, including examples of symbols you want to consider unrecognized. I don't have particular experience with this or other gesture classification libraries though, so I can't give you a complete answer.

Comment: I answered a [similar question here, with an alternative to $P](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/90609/7804). Maybe it's useful, or a duplicate?

Answer (score 5):

Because you need it to be picky (like a security code <- *hint* *hint*) use a more low-tech method.

Divide your rune drawing area into a grid of NxN (5x5 works well, 3x3 for a very small rune selection).

Consider the strike to hit the area only when it is within a certain distance from the center of the grid cell.

Record the cell hits in order as a string (e.g.: "E0D1C2B3A4,C1B2C3D2C1" below) compare the string to the valid runes.

[image]

You can (should) display a pattern to help the players line up their strokes. You can disguise it as some occult pattern in the style of the game.

[image]

Otherwise you may have to first rescale the gesture grid to fit the drawn area (or vice-versa) but that would limit you to edge-to-edge rune patterns.

---

Another method (below) is to only record the *direction* of the strokes with the distance filtered out regardless of the starting point: (north, north-west, west, east)

[image]

The difficult part is properly filtering out the bounces between directions. One way is to use 8 directions for the rune but detect 16 (north, NNW, north-west, NWW, west, ...) and retain the previous one-in-8 direction when you hit the in-between directions.
And use a drag distance threshold before recording a direction.

So if you detect (N, NNW, NW, NNW, NW, NWW, W, E) the output will be (N, N, NW, NW, NW, NW, W, E) then filter out the duplicates giving you (N, NW, W, E).

Comment: interesting. Will definitely look into your approach. But I dont want it to be super picky. I want the player to be able to draw his rune anywhere on the screen. Like in arx fatalis or this video https://youtu.be/ISutk1mauPM?t=325

Comment: Then I'd use the 2nd approach (directions without location) and add considering self-intersection of the gesture lines to **detect loops**, then you can also add a consideration for loop size relative to the other segment sizes and directions as a way to differentiate runes or power if that is part of the game's design.
(e.g.: the stroke example you linked would be: NW, CCW-Loop, W) You could also on top of this consider the overall elongation of the loop and its elongation axis (e.g.: >3:2 elongated or 1:1 to 3:2 circular). You can tweak those criteria to your liking to adjust difficulty.