# Comparing analog stick movements to predefined flick shapes

Tags: unity, c#, algorithm, input, gestures

I want to create a control scheme similar to the EA Skate games, where flicking the right analog stick in various ways makes the character do various tricks:

[image: Diagram of flick patterns in EA Skate]

I record the user input over a set amount of time or until the user moves the analog stick back to its resting position. The recording is a List of Vector2 Coordinates.

Depending on how fast the user flicks the analogue stick, I sometimes get a shorter (15) or longer (45) list of points.

Now I want to compare these lists of points to predefined shapes like the ones in the screenshot, to match which action the player intended to take.

My idea was to use some metric to compare the similarity of the recording to lists of arrays, however, I don't which metric I might use. I found the Hausdorff-Metric and it seems applicable, but I don't know how to implement it.
It might also be an overkill for the problem, so I wanted to ask, how other people would solve the problem.

Comment: This can be done using [techniques similar to hand-drawn character recognition](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/120413/39518) - your "drawing cursor" is just more restricted (which also simplifies the problem of normalizing the bounds of the drawing). For the analog stick case, you might want to use a radial grid rather than a rectangular grid as shown in that answer, and potentially track time lingering in a particular sector if that's relevant to your use case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like all these gestures only care about which points you hit around the outside of the stick's range, and the order you hit them in, so we can take a very simplified approach.

Let's label each sector in the outer ring with a letter:

[image: Ring labeling example]

Each time the stick lands in a new one of these sectors, we'll add that letter to a string. We won't repeat a letter if you linger in the same sector, and we won't care about the exact path you took to get there, as long as you didn't hit another sector in-between.

Now each combo is just a string of letters:

- Ollie: EA (appropriately enough )
- Heelflip: EB
- Kickflip: EH
- Nollie FS 360 Pop Shuvit: GHABC

We'll set up a script that pairs up each combo with one or more letter strings that should trigger it. (Having some "synonymous" strings helps you handle slight overshoots/misalignments, making the tricks easier to do even if the player's a little sloppy)

Here's what that can look like:

[image: Inspector example]

An example gesture recognizer might then look like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnalogFlick : MonoBehaviour {
    // How many segments to divide the ring into.
    const int BUCKET_COUNT = 8;

    // Data structure to define combos.
    // You can add to this things like animations, point values, etc.
    // Or make it a ScriptableObject that can live as a separate asset.
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Combo {
        public string name;
        public string[] patterns;
    }

    // Gesture detection parameters.
    public float deadzoneRadius = 0.2f;
    public float activationRadius = 0.8f;
    public float maxGestureDuration = 1f;

    public Combo[] combos;

    Dictionary<string, Combo> _patternMatch = new Dictionary<string, Combo>();
    StringBuilder _progress = new StringBuilder();

    float _gestureDuration = 0f;
    [SerializeField]
    int _lastBucket;
    int _framesInDeadzone;
    bool _readyToBegin;

    string _patternInProgress = "";



    void Start() {
        // Convert our Inspector list of combos into a dictionary for quick string lookups.
        foreach (var combo in combos) {
            foreach (var pattern in combo.patterns)
                _patternMatch.Add(pattern, combo);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        // Collect our input and magnitude.
        Vector2 stick = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));

#if UNITY_EDITOR
        _analogHistory[Time.frameCount & 31] = stick;
#endif

        float magnitude = stick.magnitude;

        // If we're mid-gesture and cross within the deadzone, the flick might be over.
        if (magnitude < deadzoneRadius) {
            // Give some tolerance to cross the deadzone during a zig-zag, before we cut off.
            if (_gestureDuration > 0f && _framesInDeadzone > 2)
                EndFlick();

            //Debug.Log("Grazed deadzone");
            _framesInDeadzone++;
            // We've returned to neutral, so we can start a new gesture if we're not already in one.
            _readyToBegin = true;
        } else {
            // Otherwise, reset our deadzone watch.
            _framesInDeadzone = 0;

            // If we've deflected far enough to start a flick...
            if (_readyToBegin == true && magnitude > activationRadius) {
                // Start a new flick if we're not already.
                if (_gestureDuration == 0f)
                    BeginFlick();

                // Abort the gesture if it's gone too long.
                _gestureDuration += Time.deltaTime;
                if (_gestureDuration > maxGestureDuration) {
                    EndFlick();

                    // Finally, try to progress the gesture using this input.
                } else if (ProgressFlick(stick)) {
                    // If we've completed a valid pattern, fire the combo and end the gesture.
                    if (CheckPattern())
                        EndFlick();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Initialize flick state.
    void BeginFlick() {
        _progress.Length = 0;
        _lastBucket = -1;
    }

    // Try appending a new entry to the combo.
    bool ProgressFlick(Vector2 stick) {        
        const float BUCKETS_PER_RADIAN = BUCKET_COUNT / (2 * Mathf.PI);

        // Get the angle of the stick, and round it to one of a fixed number of buckets.
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(-stick.x, -stick.y);
        int bucket = Mathf.RoundToInt(angle * BUCKETS_PER_RADIAN + BUCKET_COUNT / 2.0f) % BUCKET_COUNT;
        // If we've changed buckets, add a new letter to our combo.
        if (bucket != _lastBucket) {
            _progress.Append((char)('A' + bucket));
            _lastBucket = bucket;
            return true;
        }
        // Otherwise, nothing new to report.
        return false;
    }

    bool CheckPattern() {
        // Read out our pattern so far...
        _patternInProgress = _progress.ToString();

        // Check whether it matches any of our combos.
        if (_patternMatch.TryGetValue(_patternInProgress, out Combo combo)) {
            Debug.LogFormat("Combo: {0} ({1})", combo.name, _patternInProgress);
            // TODO: Do the combo's trick!

            _patternInProgress = "";
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    void EndFlick() {
        // For debugging, it's useful to know what the algorithm "thought" you entered.
        if (_patternInProgress != "")
            Debug.LogFormat("Unknown Combo: {0}", _patternInProgress);

        // Mark the gesture as over.
        _gestureDuration = 0f;
        // But don't let us start a new gesture till we return to neutral.
        _readyToBegin = false;
        _patternInProgress = "";
    }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    Vector2[] _analogHistory = new Vector2[32];
    private void OnDrawGizmos() {
        Gizmos.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(transform.position, Quaternion.identity, new Vector3(1, 1, 0));
        Gizmos.color = Color.white;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(Vector3.zero, 1.0f);
        Gizmos.color = Color.grey;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(Vector3.zero, activationRadius);
        Gizmos.color = Color.black;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(Vector3.zero, deadzoneRadius);

        Gizmos.color = Color.grey;
        for(int i = 0; i < BUCKET_COUNT; i++) {
            Vector3 direction = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, (360.0f / BUCKET_COUNT) * (i + 0.5f)) * Vector3.up;
            Gizmos.DrawLine( 1f * direction,  activationRadius * direction);           
        }

        Gizmos.color = _gestureDuration == 0f ? Color.blue : Color.red;
        Vector3 lastPosition = _analogHistory[(Time.frameCount + 1) & 31];
        for (int x = 2; x <= 32; x++) {
            var next = _analogHistory[(Time.frameCount + x) & 31];
            Gizmos.DrawLine(lastPosition, next);
            lastPosition = next;
        }

        Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(lastPosition, 0.1f);
    }
#endif
}
```

This script also comes with a handy input visualizer to help you see what different flicks look like, and adjust the tuning of your radii:

[image: Visualizer Gizmo]

You can improve on this in various ways - adding a little hysteresis to reduce false positives when input is close to the edge of a sector, tuning the diagonal buckets so they're a bit wider to compensate for the cardinal directions being easier to hit, or keeping a running history buffer and checking multiple pattern lengths in that buffer so you don't need a hard return-to-neutral reset between gestures. But this basic idea should get you quite a long way. And the simplicity makes it easy to author gestures for, easy to debug when it's misbehaving, and rock-solid in terms of consistency & reliability for the player.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a nice answer and it works great. The only issue I have is that the change from H to A is at an angle of 90°. I tried to offset it by 1/8th of Pi, so that the change is slightly to the right at 3/8th of Pi ( as in the diagram) but it didn't work. I understood that you used ``angle = Mathf.Atan2(-stick.x, -stick.y);` insteaod of `angle = Mathf.Atan2(stick.y, stick.x);` as the angle in order to offset where the first bucket will be. But I don't see what `RAD_TO_BUCKET` acutally means. I tried to come up with my own solution and would use the inverse. Anyway thanks!

Comment: @Toto That'll teach me to try to do math at 3 AM. Corrected version above. `RAD_TO_BUCKET` is short for "radians to bucket" so I renamed it to `BUCKETS_PER_RADIAN` in the new version. It's the conversion factor between radian angles (-\$\pi\$ to \$\pi\$) to bucket indices (-4 to 4). We then round to the nearest integer to group all the values in each bucket to a single value, then add 4 to cycle around. Values at/above 3.5 round to 4, which goes up to 8, so we take modulo 8 to wrap back around to 0 (A).

Comment: I've built a different solution after remembering first semester radial math again ;). I've defined `BUCKET_RADIUS = ` (2 * Mathf.PI) / BUCKET_COUNT;` and a starting angle of $ 0.5\pi + 0.5 BUCKET_RADIUS $ and using the actual angle `angle = Mathf.Atan2(stick.y, stick.x);`. I calculate the difference from the angle to the starting angle (adding $ 2\pi $ if it's negative), and divide by BUCKET_RADIUS. It works, albeit it might have some additional lines of code. The visualizer is very nice, I'll check it out when I'm on my Dev-System again.